How to handle endianness in variable length payloads with named fields?
I am implementing a custom communication protocol which uses payloads of variable lengths. I need to access both the raw bytes of the payload as well as named fields which correspond to specific bits/bytes.
My intuition was to use a union with a struct for the named fields, e.g.
#pragma pack(push, 1)

union Payload1
{
  uint8_t *raw_bytes;

  struct
  {
    uint16_t value_1;    // 2 byte value
    uint32_t value_2;    // 4 byte value
    uint8_t value_3;     // 1 byte value
    uint8_t flag_1 : 1;  // flag bit
    uint8_t : 7;         // reserved bits
    // other values
  };
};

// other payloads

#pragma pack(pop)

I also use the pack directive to byte-align my memory. However, I run into issues regarding endianness. The data received is in big-endian style i.e., the most significant byte is received first. I have to write many payloads like this. Is there a generic and scalable way to implement this for both little-endian and big-endian architectures?

Bit-fields?  #pragma pack()?  First read this: What is the strict aliasing rule? as you're almost certainly violating that and invoking undefined behavior.  Second, both #pragma pack() and bit-fields pretty much ensure a non-portable implementation.

If it is a communication protocol, then I suggest you actually use some well known and widely used serialization format. Like Json or protobuf or whatever. Don't reinvent the wheel.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html
Also, your raw_bytes probably doesn't want to be a pointer...

Use a binary serialization library like protobuf! (or flatbuffers). Also bitfields do not do what you think they do, they are not portable. The memory layout is not standardized (it might not even use bits, just makes your member behave as if it was an int with 1 or 7 bits)

Also not, union in C++ does not do what it does in "C" and should in practice NOT be used in C++ unless you really understand ALL the ways in which it can fail (cause UB).  On top of that type punning or casting memory to a type other than the most basic trivially copyable/assignabe/constructible/destructible classes/types is not going to end well. (If you don't know what this all means don't try to do what you are doing) and just get a library to do serialization for you (because your intuition is totally going to fail you). At best you get something that seems to work on your machine.

ntoh and hton.  Where h stands for host endian, and n stands for network endian.

In our company framework, I wrote a type-safe template variadic function for that type of purposes. It is used like this: socket->writeStructure("< U16 U32 U1 G7", value_1, value_2, value_3); for output, and symmetrically  socket->readStructure("< U16 U32 U1 G7", &value_1, &value_2, &value_3); for input. Proved to be very handy. (< means big endian, U# unsigned integers, G7 gap of 7 bits)

I could add that my functions read/writeStructure were aimed to solve simultaneously all three of your problems and tags: memory alignment, endianness and support for bit fields. In a fully platform independent way, no UB, and handy syntax.

I think this is a duplicate of How to write endian agnostic C/C++ code?, which has an accepted answer that I think is a good solution for the specific situation here: do not try to parse binary data by forcing the layout of a struct to match it.  Instead, parse the data byte by byte and copy it into whatever in-memory structure is appropriate for later processing.

This approach only works om networks with similar endpoints(same HW, OS and toolchain). On such networks, endianness is irrelevant. If you want portable code, you must avoid UB and implementation defined behavior. Raw pointers, naked unions, bit fields, reinterpret_cast call for demons. There's no simple enough answer to your question. You need to become a true C++ programmer to solve that kind of thing.
